# Is year view and month view provided by FSCalendar in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, fscalendar

Currently I am using the `FSCalendar` (https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) library with interface build as suggested by `FSCalendar` in my iOS application. Now, my requirement is to display month view and year view. In a month view I have to display current or any month which user want with all dates while in a year view I have to display 12 month of any year. I have checked and do research on `FSCalendar` library but I am unable to find this kind of feature. If anyone know how to implement this feature or enable this feature in `FSCalendar` library that would be appreciated.

Comment: I've never heard of FSCalendar. Unless it's a widely used library you might not get any responses. Have you tried posting a question to the framework author, or seeing if there is a support channel listed in the Git repo?

Comment: They. don't have this feature by default. they only have a week and month view. You have to create this functionality by yourself. I have messed up my brain a lot with FSCalender library earlier. It will take time but you can build it.

Comment: @DuncanC i have posted in their git repo also but not getting any response from them. And yes it's widely used library by developer.

Comment: @mAc It will take too much time to create by our own that feature. I have urgency to use this feature in my project.

Comment: @Birju If it is urgent, maybe you can hire a consultant to help you.

Comment: And maybe you can fins some inspiration here: https://github.com/fggeraissate/FFCalendar